# border-radius IS working in select rules in I.E 8 why?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

In [this site](http://taylorstrategy.com/) rounded corners is working in I.E 8
from what I know border-radius is not supported until I.E 9
Still, there is one div (only one)where border radius is not working, that's the red one in the bottom right.

```
 div class=specialSidebar
```

There is no special filter: properties applied here from what I can see. 
the other divs have border-radius working if you go in with developer tools with I.E 8 and uncheck border-radius they become square.

Answer (score 1):

Have a peek at their CSS, http://taylorstrategy.com/wp-content/themes/taylorStrategy/style.css

```
/*Right Sidebar*/
.rightSidebar {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 14px 30px 10px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;     

}
```

I believe in IE8 they are using javascript (jQuery) to replace the border-radius with rounded corners. Have a peek at [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aRounded_Corners) for further info.

Comment: I don't think so. I do not see a javascript file to generate rounded corners, and all those divs have same styles.  .rightSidebar is the only one without rounded divs.